# How to display the first N lines of a command output in Windows? (the equivalent of Unix command "head")

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, command-line-interface

I need an equivalent of the Unix `head` command (display the first N lines of the output). This is what I'm using currently:

```
tasklist | find /N " " | findstr /r \[[0-9]\]
```

The above code displays the first 10 lines of `tasklist`'s output. `find /N " "` prepends a line number to the start of each line while `findstr /r \[[0-9]\]` extracts the first 10 lines using regex.

Above code works, but I need to **specify any range**. Due to the fact that regular expressions are not implemented according to the standards in Windows, I can't get anything else to work.

How can I extract arbitrary lines from a cmd output? It is important to do this with a one-liner. No scripts!

Comment: .....................

Comment: Nice workaround for a simple usecase, we say: In hard times, the devil eats flies.

Answer (score 45):

Powershell.

`PS C:\> netstat | Select -First 20`

Edit: I have a feeling that you're going to insist that you're only able to use cmd.exe circa 1989, but that's not true. Powershell is baked into every OS version Vista+, and is installable on XP/2003.  It **is** the future of Windows.

Edit: Alright, have it your way.

```
C:\> netstat -an > temp.txt && for /l %l in (1,1,10) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %a in ('findstr /n /r "^" temp.txt ^| findstr /r "^%l:"') do @echo %b
```

Will display the first 10 lines of the output of netstat.

Comment: I have no doubt that PowerShell is the future, but I need something that works, now. In an enterprise reality, often the customers of our tech support department have hundreds of windows servers, none of which have Vista, 7 or 8. I can't possibly waste time installing PowerShell every time I need to run a command, nor am I even authorized to.

Comment: Cmd.exe it is...

Comment: all they would need is one w2k8r2 server that they CAN log into to run a powershell command, is that possible?

Comment: I don't know if there are 2K8 servers, but Ryan Ries's answer is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much Ryan!

Comment: Please don't forget to... mark the answer as... accepted... :`( *curls up in fetal position in the corner and sobs to self*

Comment: Please could someone explain how the cmd.exe solution works?

Comment: @giecsar: what Os are those 'servers' running?

Comment: @RyanRies, I don't know why "installable on XP/2003" is such an epiphany.... there're tons of programs that are "installable on XP/2003".

Answer (score 7):

If you are a Unix type person, perhaps installing [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) gives you a more familiar environment.

Comment: No, I thought I made it clear, but I can't installing anything. It must run with the Windows command processor (cmd.exe). No PowerShell, no CygWin, no scripts.

Comment: Plz. remove Cygwin, cannot see it anymore. It is from `yesterday`.

Answer (score 5):

There's an easy solution that's much easier than using the "`for`" loop.

Let's take the output from `dir/o-d` (`dir` inverse-ordered by date) as an example.

E.g. if you want to output lines 1 to 16, use:

```
dir/o-d|findstr/n ^^|findstr "^[1-9]: ^1[0-6]:"
```

E.g. if you want to output lines 16 to 45, use:

```
dir/o-d|findstr/n ^^|findstr "^1[6-9]: ^[2-3][0-9]: ^4[0-5]:"
```

Sample output:

```
16:08/08/2016  08:43 AM    <DIR>          nacl_sdk
17:11/05/2016  10:48 PM    <DIR>          3b 2
18:28/04/2016  02:47 PM    <DIR>          sample
19:22/04/2016  10:07 PM    <DIR>          mysql test
20:16/04/2016  01:22 AM    <DIR>          3b
21:16/04/2016  01:10 AM             2,706 errorlog
22:16/04/2016  12:53 AM                 0 accesslog
...
```

Breakdown:

- Aside from the [unsupported features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2007/08/29/how-to-use-findstr-with-regular-expression.aspx), `findstr`'s regex is actually working properly. Your issue is with [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3813370/632951). (See [Rob's reference](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for details.)

1. First, dump the whole output using `dir/o-d`.
2. Next, prepend each line with "`$Num:`" using `findstr/n ^^`

   - `^` means match start of line, and `^^` is simply it's escaped version required because we are in cmd.
   - Note: you need to use `findstr` for this because `find/n" "` will not match lines without spaces`.
3. Lastly,  crop the output using `findstr "^1[6-9]: ^[2-3][0-9]: ^4[0-5]:"`.

   - `^1[6-9]:` is regex for 16 to 19.
   - `^[2-3][0-9]:` is regex for 20 - 39.
   - `^4[0-5]:` is regex for 40 to 45.
   - `findstr "a b c"` means find strings which match either expressions `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/632951

Comment: That's a nice solution, but you now have the number prefixed there, can one get rid of them in the last findstr call?

Comment: @fschmitt, `findstr` cannot remove things. I'd think you might be forced to use a loop then in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-line-command, I hope it works for you too.

```
@echo off&cls&for /f "tokens=*" %a in (Graph.bat) do echo %a&for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %a in (Graph.bat) do echo %a&for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %a in (Graph.bat) do echo %a&for /f "skip=3 tokens=*" %a in (Graph.bat) do echo %a&for /f "skip=4 tokens=*" %a in (Graph.bat) do echo %a&pause>nul

:: Run this from CMD.exe and make sure that your file is in your current working directory.

::Replace Graph.bat with your file.
```

Comment: Will this work for lines starting with semicolon ; or blank lines?